# Gatsby develop showing old code I've removed

Tags: gatsby

I have a Gatsby project using Bun. Today suddenly gatsby develop is showing me code changes I've removed. For example, theres a react component A rendering another component B. Even if I remove B from A, the site still shows B and even tracks changes in B in live preview.

I've tried deleting .cache and public dirs and even node_modules. Tried gatsby clean as well. I can't see mention of any other cache location in Gatsby docs. I've tried in other browsers as well. Any idea why its picking up an old code?